# PHP Injection from HTTP GET data used as PHP array key value

Tags: php, code-injection

i would like to know if there is a possible injection of code (or any other security risk like reading memory blocks that you weren't supposed to etc...) in the following scenario, where **unsanitized data** from HTTP GET **is used in code** of PHP **as KEY of array.**

This supposed to transform letters to their order in alphabet. a to 1, b to 2, c to 3 .... HTTP GET "letter" variable supposed to have values letters, but as you can understand anything can be send to server:

HTML:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?letter=[anything in here, as dirty it can gets]
```

PHP:

```
$dirty_data = $_GET['letter'];

echo "Your letter's order in alphabet is:".Letter2Number($dirty_data);

function Letter2Number($my_array_key)
{
    $alphabet = array("a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3");

    // And now we will eventually use HTTP GET unsanitized data
    // as a KEY for a PHP array... Yikes!

    return $alphabet[$my_array_key]; 

}
```

Questions:

1. Do you see any security risks?
2. How can i sanitize HTTP data to be able use them in code as KEY of an array?
3. How bad is this practice?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341034/avoiding-xss-when-echoing-posted-html

Comment: It's not exactly a security risk in this code, but keep in mind that Letter2Number might return something ugly like `NULL` which could theoretically be a security risk elsewhere in the code if you don't check for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't see any problems with this practice. Anything you... errr... get from `$_GET` is a string. It will not pose any security threat whatsoever unless you call [`eval()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) on it. Any string can be used as a PHP array key, and it will have no adverse effects whatsoever (although if you use a really long string, obviously this will impact memory usage).

It's not like SQL, where you are building code to be execut**ed** later - your PHP code has already been built and is execut**ing**, and the only way you can modify the way in which it executes at runtime is by calling `eval()` or `include()`/`require()`.

**EDIT**

Thinking about it there are a couple of other ways, apart from `eval()` and `include()`, that this input *could* affect the operation of the script, and that is to use the supplied string to dynamically call a function/method, instantiate an object, or in variable variables/properties. So for example:

```
$userdata = $_GET['userdata'];

$userdata();
// ...or...
$obj->$userdata();
// ...or...
$obj = new $userdata();
// ...or...
$someval = ${'a_var_called_'.$userdata};
// ...or...
$someval = $obj->$userdata;
```

...would be a very bad idea, if you were to do it with sanitizing `$userdata` first.

However, for what you are doing, you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: PHP unfortunately doesn't guarantee that anything from $_GET is a string, it could also be an array. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Input_handling  . This complicates any answer involving user input, especially since PHP often silently passes over type errors, with often surprising outcomes.

Answer (score 3):

Any external received from `GET`, `POST`, `FILE`, etc. should be treated as filthy and sanitized appropriately.  How and when you sanitize depends on when the data is going to be used.  If you are going to store it to the DB, it needs to be escaped (to avoid SQL Injection.  [See PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) for example).  Escaping is also necessary when running an OS command based on user data such as `eval` or attempting to read a file (like reading `../../../etc/passwd`).  If it's going to be displayed back to the user, it needs to be encoded (to avoid html injection. [See htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for example).

You don't have to sanitize data for the way you are using it above.  In fact, you should only escape for storage and encode for display, but otherwise leave data raw.  Of course, you may want to perform your own validation on the data.  For example, you may want `dirty_data` to be in the list of `[a, b, c]` and if not echo it back to the user.  Then you would have to encode it.

Any well-known OS is not going to have a problem even if the user managed to attempt to read an invalid memory address.

Answer (score 0):

1. Presumably this array's contents are meant to be publicly accessible in this way, so no.
2. Run it through `array_key_exists()`
3. Probably at least a little bad.  Maybe there's something that could be done with a malformed multibyte string or something that could trigger some kind of overflow on a poorly-configured server... but that's pure (ignorant) speculation on my part.